# Is Samsung 950 PRO M2 compatible with ASUS P9X79 DELUXE mobo?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express

I am impressed by the read/write times of the Samsung 950 PRO M2. I have a slightly out of date mobo: the ASUS P9X79 DELUXE. I do not see an M2 port listed in the mobo specs; however, it does have PCIe expansion slots:

3 x PCIe 3.0x16 slots (Dual@x16/x16; Triple@x16/x8/x8)

1 x PCIe 3.0x16 slot (PCIe x 16_3@x8)

Is there some way that I can use the Samsung 950 PRO M2 with this mobo? Perhaps there is a M2 module that can convert the PCIe slot to fit the M2 connector? Will I still see the same performance?

Comment: If you can find a M.2 PCI-E card then you can use it.  You might not be able to boot to it though.

Comment: @Ramhound: is there a way to determine bootability?

Comment: @sapbucket did you ever find an answer for this or tried it out yourself.. particularly the bootability of the 950 Pro on a P9X79?

Comment: I found out that it probably won't work (90% sure). I forget the reason why but it had to do with even if you get it installed it won't perform at the higher speed. Short story: get a new motherboard with the correct features built in.

Answer (score -1):

One of these or something similar should do the trick...

http://www.amazon.co.uk/LyCOM-DT-120-Lycom-PCI-e-Adapter/dp/B00MYCQP38/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448755630&sr=8-1&keywords=m.2+pcie+card

Is this what you were looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: So modules do exist. I'll keep investigating. I'm not sure if this entirely answers my question.